# Reading android's current theme's properties

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am replacing the `AlertDialog.Builder` title with a custom inflated layout.

```
customTitle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_title_custom);
// Blar blar, some extra code.
builder.setCustomTitle(customTitle);
```

As you can see by the pictures below (on the right), it works. The button triggers events, and everything is all hunky dorey.

[image: Dialog Before and After]

But what I am trying to do now is make the Title text look exactly like the Theme's native title in Colour/Size/Padding/Gravity/etc/etc but I do not know how to get access to the original/theme's settings to do this.
I thought I had found it with

```
@android:style/TextApperance.DialogWindowTitle
```

But I do not know how to apply it within the `dialog_title_custom.xml`. I have tried the two lines below. The first one gives the above Title output (on the right). But I wish to have it look light the dialog on the Left.

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle"
```

The second gives me a "Binary XML file line #7" error.

```
android:textStyle="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle"
```

I know I can play around with the padding numbers to precisely match a Blue text colour and Font size X and Padding Y with hardcode values. I wish to be able to integrate whatever the current themes Default DialogWindowTitle settings happens to be and use their values to give the user a unified system feel.